# PythonからWindowsAPIを呼び出して、%APPDATA%のパスを取得したい

Tags: python, windows

PythonからWindowsの%APPDATA%のパスを取得しようとした場合、以下のコマンドで実行することが出来ます。

```
import os
os.getenv('APPDATA')
```

ただし、これだと稀に正しいパスを取得できない環境があるのではないかと思う場面に遭遇したため、WindowsAPIを使用してパスの取得を試してみたいと考えています。

[Advanced Installerのドキュメント](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html#install-location)に書かれている`Recommended API calls for retrieving your AppData folder paths:`を参考に、次のコマンドを試してみましたが、取得できませんでした。

```
from ctypes import *

user32 = windll.user32
AppDataPath = user32.Environment.GetFolderPath(user32.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
print(AppDataPath)
```

エラー内容は次の通りです。

```
AttributeError: function 'Environment' not found
```

PythonからWindowsAPIを呼び出し、%APPDATA%のパスを取得するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WindowsAPIなら[SHGetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha?redirectedfrom=MSDN)で取得できます。
なお、この場合`windll.user32`ではなく`win32com.shell`を利用します。

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

path = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_APPDATA, None, 0)
print(path) # C:\Users\Hoge\AppData\Roaming
```

Comment: 提示頂いたコードでパスを取得できました！